# Swift get json with Codable

Tags: json, swift

I want get json by encode model, which inherit a base class, and conforms to  protocol `Codable`. But it failed.
Here is the code:

```
// this is a func to get json
func getJson<T>(model: T) throws -> String where T: AnyObject, T: Codable {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let data = try encoder.encode(model)
    if let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        return json
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}


class BaseClass: Codable {
    var bx = 0
}

class SubClass: BaseClass  {
    var x = 1
    var y = 2
}

// test if get json enable
func test1() throws {
    let source = SubClass()
    let json = try getJson(model: source)
    print(json)
}

// how can i get json by this code
func test2() throws {
    let source = SubClass()

    var any: BaseClass?
    any = source
    let json = try getJson(model: any!)
    print(json)
}
```

I modifed the code like below , then the func `test1()` backed right json, but func `test2()` was error :

```
class BaseClass {
    var bx = 0
}

class SubClass: BaseClass, Codable  {
    var x = 1
    var y = 2
}
```

Looking forward to your help !

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: `Argument type 'BaseClass' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'`
The class `BaseClass` is not conforms to `Codable`.

Comment: I added the answer see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encodable and Decodable involve some code synthesis where the compiler essentially writes the code for you. When you conform BaseClass to Codable, these methods are written to the BaseClass class and hence they are not aware of any additional properties defined by SubClass. You have to override the encode(to:) method in your subclass:

```
class BaseClass: Codable {
    var bx = 0
}

class SubClass: BaseClass  {
    var x = 1
    var y = 2

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case x
        case y
    }

    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try super.encode(to: encoder)
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.x, forKey: .x)
        try container.encode(self.y, forKey: .y)
    }
}
```

Comment: I try the code, it works. But there is 100+ net interface in my project, it's huge amount of work.

Comment: Yes you will have to do that if you have that big hierarchy. May be i will suggest try using composition wherever possible instead on inheritance.

Comment: May be, i can use `KVC` instead of `Codable`.

Comment: Can you give a example of composition ? I changed the code, but get an error of `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`.
`
func test2() throws {
    let source = SubClass()
    var any: (BaseClass & Codable)?
    any = source
    let json = try getJson(model: any!)
    print(json)
}
`

Comment: Give me gist, i will see if i can help.

Comment: [https://gist.github.com/anqingZ/f9fb75e199e6b113c875a9dda0812aea](https://gist.github.com/anqingZ/f9fb75e199e6b113c875a9dda0812aea) Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in  
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let responseModel = try jsonDecoder.decode(Json4Swift_Base.self, from: data!)

}
task.resume()

struct Json4Swift_Base : Codable {

let gameID : Int?
let start : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case gameID = "gameID"
    case start = "start"

}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    gameID = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .gameID)
    start = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .start)
}

}
```

If you need more help this website is very helpful to convert your json models http://www.json4swift.com

Comment: It an idea,  but not it's inconvenience.

Answer (score -1):

I modified your code, you can check it out.

```
 func getJson<T>(model: T) throws -> String where T: AnyObject, T: Codable {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let data = try encoder.encode(model)
    if let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        return json
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}


class BaseClass: Codable {
    var x : Int
    var y: Int
    init(x bx: Int, y by: Int) {
        x = bx
        y = by
    }
}

class SubClass: BaseClass {
    override init(x bx: Int, y by: Int) {
        super.init(x: bx, y: by)
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        fatalError("init(from:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// test if get json enable
func test1() throws {
    let source = SubClass(x: 1, y: 6)
    let json = try getJson(model: source)
    print(json)
}
```

Comment: In fact , it will be none property in baseClass. I just want use a baseClass conforms to `Codable`. So i  can get json by ` func getJson<T>(model: T) throws -> String where T: AnyObject, T: Codable`.